TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method. Trying to reduce data size
I refer to the answer given by Daniel Goldfarb here in reference to slicing data (at the very end of the answer). I have tried to implement the same sort of thing as follows:
        data_type = params.get_param("DataType")
        format = ''
        if data_type == 'Daily':
            format = "%Y-%m-%d"
        else:
            format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

        df = pd.read_csv(data_file, parse_dates = True, date_format = format)
        df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date2']) # My date column that is the index
    
        start_date = '2024-03-01'
        end_date = '2024-06-01'
        df = df.index[start_date:end_date] 

But I get the following stacktrace at the last line:
  File "/data/stuart/Projects/Python/BackTesting/MA_Crossover/MA_Crossover3.py", line 520, in <module>
    main_strategy(df, ticker)
  File "/data/stuart/Projects/Python/BackTesting/MA_Crossover/MA_Crossover3.py", line 486, in main_strategy
    plot_chart(ticker, data_output_file, params_file)
  File "/data/stuart/Projects/Python/BackTesting/BackTestPkg/Charting.py", line 155, in plot_chart
    df = df.index[start_date:end_date]
         ~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/stuart/Projects/Python/Env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 5394, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_slice(key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/stuart/Projects/Python/Env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 5429, in _getitem_slice
    res = self._data[slobj]
          ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^
  File "/data/stuart/Projects/Python/Env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimelike.py", line 381, in __getitem__
    result = cast("Union[Self, DTScalarOrNaT]", super().__getitem__(key))
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/stuart/Projects/Python/Env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/_mixins.py", line 293, in __getitem__
    result = self._ndarray[key]
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Can anybody suggest a way forward (I am fairly new to Python).

Try with df = df.loc[start_date:end_date] instead of df = df.index[start_date:end_date].

Be sure to add the pandas tag if your issue is related to the library and not python in general.

It is because you are trying to slice a DatetimeIndex directly on the index. Instead, you should use the loc method to slice the DataFrame based on the date range:
    data_type = params.get_param("DataType")
    format = ''
    if data_type == 'Daily':
        format = "%Y-%m-%d"
    else:
        format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

    df = pd.read_csv(data_file, parse_dates = True, date_format = format)
    df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date2']) # My date column that is the index

    start_date = '2024-03-01'
    end_date = '2024-06-01'

    # Use .loc to slice the DataFrame based on the date range
    df = df.loc[start_date:end_date]

After setting the index, you should use loc to slice the DataFrame using date strings.

Thank you very much to all that contributed. df = df.loc[start_date:end_date] did the trick.
